# Why can a typedef not share a name with an object but a tag can?

Tags: c, struct, alias, typedef

What are the specific and applied reasons of why can a typedef not share a name with an object but a tag can? I can't help but feeling like there is some huge concept I am missing; that suggests a typedef is doing something a tag is not and merely being a synonym for an existing arrangement does not answer the question of why the difference exists.

```
//Allowed:
struct i {int i;};
struct i i;

//Or:
struct {int i;} i;
///////////////////////////////
//Not allowed:
typedef struct i {int i;} i;
i i;

//Nor:
typedef struct {int i;} i;
i i;
```

Comment: It's just a matter of avoiding syntactic ambiguities.  The tag for a `struct`, `union`, or `enum` always follows those keywords when referenced, so there is no chance of ambiguity.  Type names, on the other hand, can result in ambiguities.  For instance, in `sizeof(x)`, `x` can be a type or a variable name.

Comment: Yes, exactly, "a typedef is doing something a tag is not". A typedef is a type name, and a lone tag is not. Only `struct tag` etc are type names. In fact this is the only context where tags can be used. `struct i` is syntactically different from `i`, so it's easy to tell which `i` is a tag and which one is not. OTOH `i` is syntactically the same as `i` (doh).

Comment: Thank you for the responses; I think the typedef sharing a place with an object as a postfix leads me to believe that the typedef therefore reserves actual space for the symbol table while the tag is just a reference group to the form of the structure.